# How do I remove the component border shown onClick in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Whenever I click on any of the components I get a black border, although when I click away the border disappears. How do I prevent the web app from doing so? 
Below there is a picture of what I get in my app.

Also, this is a link to a sandbox where I have the same issue: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/es6-spread-operator-practice-drbyh?file=/src/components/App.jsx

[image]

Comment: Add this css rule to the button : outline: 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by the `&focus` css selector as shown bij the inspector.

[image]

Add `outline: none` to the `<button>` to remove it;

```
<button style={{outline: 'none'}} onClick={onInputSubmit}>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `:focus` [pseudo-class](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) is adding an `outline` into the button. You can change that behaviour by using css like this:

```
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Or by adding it as an inline style as well, even though I personally don't recommend it because having a lot of inline styles could cause to have a messy and hard to read HTML.